# How to get date difference using subquery in Hive

Tags: sql, hive

In Hive, I have a query to get the min date of a product

```
SELECT min(expire_date) FROM warehouse WHERE product='Salad'
```

And get the result '2017-03-04'.

I also have a query to get the date diff for all product and it is working

```
SELECT product, import_date, datediff(import_date, '2017-01-01')+1, product from warehouse WHERE product='Salad';
```

But I when want to combine the date diff:

```
SELECT product, import_date, datediff(import_date, 'SELECT min(expire_date) FROM warehouse WHERE product=\'Salad\'')+1, from warehouse WHERE product='Salad';
```

I will have the following:

```
Salad 2017-04-23    NULL
Salad 2017-04-23    NULL
Salad 2017-04-18    NULL
```

Why does datediff can't calculate the datediff anymore, anyone has ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use window functions:

```
SELECT product, import_date, datediff(import_date, min(expire_date) over (partition by salad))
FROM warehouse
WHERE product = 'Salad';
```

A string is not going to be interpreted as a subquery.

(You can add 1 if that is what you really want the logic to do.)

Answer (score 0):

This should give the desired result

```
SELECT w.product, w.import_date, datediff(w.import_date, t.min_date)+1, from warehouse w, (SELECT min(expire_date) as min_date FROM warehouse WHERE product='Salad') t WHERE w.product='Salad';
```